# Create an alert within NetSuite that sends out an email when any of these sales channels have no sales after 2 hours?

Tags: email, netsuite, erp

I am trying to create an alert on my saved search that will email when any of our sales channels do not have an order created within 2 hours.

This is the results criteria for the saved search

[image: 1]

The lead source are the sales channels, and maximum of date created is the last time there was an order created. If it goes past 2 hours I want to be notified via email.

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to create purely within the UI.

You could create a scheduled script which will load the search, parse the results for any that are older than your threshold, and send the email from the search.  This would run periodically depending on your deployment settings.  Scheduled scripts can be deployed to run every 15 minutes, so the latest order may be up to ~2:15 old before the alert is sent.

Another approach may be to use a workflow which initiates on record creation and then has a 2 hour delay.  Following the delay it could run a search for any newer orders, then if any are found it could simply exit, or if no newer orders are found it could proceed to sending an email.  The actual implementation of running the saved search and acting based on the results will probably require a  SuiteScript custom workflow action.